# How to prevent external HDD from losing partition on power loss

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive

So I have the following setup:

- Desktop running Linux Mint
- An external USB 3.0 Hard Drive Enclosure (specifically this [one](https://www.newegg.com/p/2HY-0034-000G2?Item=9SIAKWFBRN1354&nm_mc=KNC-MSNSearch&cm_mmc=KNC-MSNSearch-_-Blu-Ray%20Media-_-Sabrent-_-9SIAKWFBRN1354&source=region&msclkid=d45180c8019f12905efbdff87f224e99&gclid=CIWTxdSbj-sCFb-PxQIdh4oJCA&gclsrc=ds))
- a 2 TB hard drive in the enclosure (specifically a Seagate Barracuda 2 TB HDD SATA 6 Gb/s NCQ 64MB Cache 3.5-Inch Internal Bare Drive ST2000DM001)
- a 320 GB SSD drive as well

Here is what happens:

- I set up the 2 TB drive as one big ext4 partition
- Everything seems to work fine
- If I lose power (has happened twice now) the hard drive partitions get wiped out on the 2 TB drive

  - Specifically, the drive is still detected but a `sudo fdisk -l` only shows the drive itself with no partitions
  - I also tried running Test Disk and got the below

```
Invalid NTFS or EXFAT boot
 0 D HPFS - NTFS          135824  27  4 288899  60 33 2459151984
  HPFS - NTFS          135824  27  4 288899  60 33 2459151984
  Linux                121420  84  9 364621 129 52 3907026944 [media]
```

- I initially thought this was because of the enclosure but I didn't lose the partition data on the 320 GB SSD drive
- Because of the above, I'm thinking it's something to do with the fact that the 2 TB is a HDD

Short of a UPS, is there anything else I could do to make this setup more resilient to power outages? e.g. should I use a different file system? Just get a big SSD?

Comment: What do you mean by 'wiped out'? Does absolutely no data in any sector remain, or does the filesystem remain but become corrupted, or does just the partition table become empty?

Comment: This sounds very broken. Please make sure you run `sync` after creating the partition - if you do, then there should be zero excuse for it missing on the next boot. Does "_power loss_" behave differently to "_shutdown / reboot_"?

Comment: A device that requires external power, then it will lose power, if there is a power outage.  Data should not be lost but there is a good reason it’s recommended to eject external devices like that HDD.  A different file system won’t prevent the device being suddenly disconnected with the lost of power.  You need to use a UPS

Comment: @user1686 I added some more detail of what the OS + TestDisk is showing me

Comment: @Attie I believe it's only on power loss but will do a test once I rebuild the partition table

Comment: i think the controller is end of life. buy new disk drive

Comment: What is the duration of your power loss?

Comment: @Attie can confirm that it's fine during regular reboot e.g. sudo shutdown -r now